# Admob crashing my app at the beginning of launch

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, ads

I decided to install Admob. However, after installing the Mobile Ads Unity plugin, the application starts and stops working at the beginning of launch. I've tried multiple solutions.

One of them I added the following codes to AndroidManifest:

```
 <application>
<uses-library android:required="false" android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"/>  
<meta-data

android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="[ADMOB APPLICATION ID]"/> //I changed only this ID
</application>
```

But this did not work. I've been through this for a long time. Can you please help? With my all respect ..

Log cat says `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArraySet"`

Comment: Did you already check the log cat to see what is the issue ?

Comment: Yes, it says "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArraySet" "

Comment: That means you have missing libraries in the Android platform. It's most common to have Multiple Dex exception when compile the game. 
Ok you only need to check if the libraries "jar" or "aar" files are in you project.
if the plugin doesn't have the support libraries just add them to your project manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 2019.1.5f1 version of unity. When Admob and GooglePlay added same project, application starts and stops working at the beginning of launch. So you need to do this;

> GoogleleMobileAds > Editor > GoogleMobileAdsDependencies

Open it with Visual Studio and change this code;

```
<androidPackage spec="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0">
```

Change it with this code;

```
<androidPackage spec="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1">
```

I hope its help you.